# Depoly Tomcat with domain name

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web, tomcat7

Can anyone please tell me that how to deploy or start tomcat with domain name

e.g.
Currently my app is working perfect with

```
http://<live-ip-address>:8080/visual/TrustDashboard
```

but i want to access it e.g.

```
http://example.com/visual/TrustDashboard
```

I've googled and found the following, but not sure it will resolve my problem as there is no entry of  port in it,

```
<Host name="domainA.com" appBase="webapps">
    <Context path="" docBase="domainA"/>
    <Alias>www.domainA.com</Alias>
    </Host>
```

Please guide me..

Comment: Is your DNS / reverse record correctly set up? This issue looks like networking, nothing java specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set up a DNS entry that points to your server. If you want to switch ports, I would use some kind of port forwarding, like IPTables to do that.

You can also change the port you're tomcat server is listening on by editing the server.xml in the conf directory. Simply find port 8080 and replace with 80. I have done this successfully in the past.

Comment: I already have the DNS entry. I just find port 8080 and replace with 80. It works Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

From [The Host Container](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html) in Tomcat docs

> The Host element represents a virtual host, which is an association of
>   a network name for a server (such as "www.mycompany.com" with the
>   particular server on which Tomcat is running. **For clients to be able
>   to connect to a Tomcat server using its network name, this name must
>   be registered in the Domain Name Service (DNS) server that manages the
>   Internet domain you belong to** - contact your Network Administrator for
>   more information.

Is not extrictly neccesary setup the `name` in the tomcat host container, but you need a DNS entry with your name for your server IP mandatorily.

Answer (score 1):

If your domainname is not registered in DNS Server.
Then for testing on your own machine you can try below

In your host file located at C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc in Windows put a entry of your domain which you want to use like

```
   <live-ip-address>  www.domainname.com
```